# I want to change this equation to a table without change anything inside it

Tags: tables, equations

```
\begin{equation}
\def\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{array}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\text{Algorithm 2 (Pseudo-code for IRS allocation and alternating beamforming)}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
    1 & Initialization: Random\, \boldsymbol{\Phi},{\textbf{\textit{W}}}, \mathcal{N}_0 = \{ 1,2,...,N \}, \mathcal{N}_k = \phi, 1 \leq k \leq K\\
    2 & \textbf{repeat} \\
   3 & With\;  \alpha_k=\frac{1}{\abs{\textbf{\textit{h}}^H_{d,k}{\textbf{\textit{w}}}_{k}}}, set\;  \ell_k=[N\frac{\alpha_k}{\sum_{i=1}^{K}\alpha_i}] \;with\; remainders\; as\; (6)\\
   4 & Order\; UEs\; as\; \alpha_{m_1}\geq\alpha_{m_2}\geq...\geq\alpha_{m_K} \\
   5 & \textbf{for}\; i=1\; \textbf{to}\; K\; \textbf{do} \\
   6 & \textbf{repeat}\\
   7 & n_0=argmax_n\abs{{f}_{n,m_i}^{*}\textbf{\textit{g}}_n^{H}\textbf{\textit{w}}_{m_i}},n \in \mathcal{N}_0\\
   8 & \mathcal{N}_{m_i} = \mathcal{N}_{m_i}+\{n_0\},\; \mathcal{N}_0 = \mathcal{N}_0-\{n_0\}\\
   9 & \textbf{until}\; Iteration\; is\; repeated\; \ell_{m_i}\; number\; of\; times\; \\
   10 & \textbf{for}\; k=1\; \textbf{to}\; K\; \textbf{do}\\
   11 & \textbf{repeat}\\
   12 & \angle{\theta_{n_k}}=-\angle{(\textbf{\textit{h}}^H_{d,k}{\textbf{\textit{w}}}_{k})}-\angle{{f}_{n_k,k}}+\angle{(\textbf{\textit{g}}^H_{n,k}{\textbf{\textit{w}}}_{k})}\\
   13 & \mathcal{N}_{k} = \mathcal{N}_{k}-\{n_k\},\; \mathcal{N}_0 = \mathcal{N}_0+\{n_k\}\\
   14 & \textbf{until}\; \mathcal{N}_{k} = \phi  \\
   15 & Update\; transmit\; beamformer\; {\textbf{\textit{W}}}\; using\; effective\; channel\; formed\; by\; \boldsymbol{\Phi}\\
   16 & \textbf{until}\; Iteration\; is\; repeated\; V>0\; number\; of\; times\; \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: change `\begin{equation}` to `\begin{table}\[` and change `\end{equation}` to `\]\end{table}` ? (Or perhaps I do not understand the question)

Comment: Probably a package dedicated to typesetting [pseudocode/algorithms](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=pseudocode) would be better suited for this kind of information?

Comment: I agree with the prior comments.  But to elaborate on the first one, this is already looking like a table.  What are you wanting to be different?

Comment: With array you need to add \text{,,,} around all text entries, with tabular you need to add $...$ around all math entries..  Otherwise the two are equivalent.

Comment: I tried it but, it didn't work out

Comment: note never use math italic for words `Update\; transmit\;` as well as dropping spaces the letters are spaced to look like a product of 1-letter variables not a word, use `\text{Update transmit}`

Comment: " it didn't work out " is not something that anyone can debug for you. Please fix your example so it is a complete small example starting `\documentclass` ending `\end{document}` and if you get an error show the exact error message.

Comment: ok I will try to fix it